# deploying clickonce application to wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce

We have created a winform application which we would like to deploy to our website which is created in wordpress (bluehost),i know how to deploy to website using publish wizard but where should i deploy is my question?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2017/11/08/using-azure-storage-for-clickonce-deployment-windows-desktop-application/

This article explains how to deploy to azure folder and expose publish.html can we do something similar on our website?